# Having issues with input type date field in Safari

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, safari

I'm puzzled as to why safari can only use the date format of YYYY-dd-mm. Is this a common issue? I want the format to be mm-dd-yyyy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Comment: Safari doesn't support date inputs. Why do you think it supports YYYY-dd-mm?

Answer (score 0):

There's no date format as of now! You should pick a date picker plugin for this solution.

---

Ambiguous solution: use `pattern` which will show error on form submission though message of the date format seems different.

[All about input type date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

**Example from MDN**

```
<input type="date" id="bday" name="bday" required
 pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}">
```

Comment: So your saying it's not possible to use the date format of `mm/dd/yyy` or `MM-dd-yyyy` in Safari? And that it's only possible to use `yyyy-dd-mm` ?

Comment: I was trying to prevent using a datepicker plugin. I'm using this package from yarn. https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/date-input-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

For input type "date",  value that would be set is always in format of "yyyy-mm-dd" where as the display format depends on locale of user's browser

Ref: [MDN Date Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Comment: So your saying it's not possible to use the date format of `mm/dd/yyy` or `MM-dd-yyyy` in Safari? And that it's only possible to use `yyyy-dd-mm` ?

Comment: I was trying to prevent using a datepicker plugin. I'm using this package from yarn. https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/date-input-polyfill

Comment: Just to clarify again what you display to the user after the date is selected can be of any format but what you eventually get from 'value' of input elem is only in the format of 'yyyy-mm-dd'.(E.g when submitting form with date input field)

Comment: How would you display a different format to the user after the date is selected though?  I'm lost. When I try to add 06/29/1995 it doesn't accept it.

Comment: I finally got the date to show up in safari by doing . ` data.birth_date = new Date("#{data.birth_date.replace(/-/g,"/")}")` but it's still in 1992-06-27 format